# Sequential runs of a program in a (bash) for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, parallel-processing

The question has been aksed several time, and I'd just like to be sure. I want to run the same program several times, on different input files. Unfortunately, when running in parallel, most of the runs crashes (I suspects some conflict between temp files names or something like that). So I want to run them in sequential while trying to figure out a better solution.

The parallel loop was :

```
N=5
(
for run in my_folders*
do
    ((i=i%N)); ((i++==0)) && wait
    myprogram --arg1=$run --arg_2 &
done
)
```

If I run it like this :

```
for run in my_folders*
do
    my_program --arg1=$run -o
done
```

Will every iteration wait for the previous one to be over ?

Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is `yes`. Why do you not give it a try and see what works and what does not and post / update the question again ?

Comment: it seems to work indeed :). Sorry for asking such a silly question.